# On click local storage setting key value twice

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm new to local storage and I'm having a bit of trouble. I have the following code:

```
    $( '#side-nav a' ).on( 'click', function() {
        var component = $( this ).attr( 'data-component' );
        var componentPath = 'components/' + component + '/index.html';
        var uid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
            var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
            return v.toString(16);
        });

        $.get( componentPath, function( data ) {
            // Add id to component
            var html = data.replace('data-uid=""','data-uid="' + uid + '"');

            localStorage.setItem( uid, html );
        });
    });
```

What I am trying to do here is:

1/ when `#sidebar-nav a` is clicked get some html from a local file, append a unique id to the `#data-uid` attribute

2/ save the uid and the manipulated string as a key / value pair to local storage.

The problem I have is that two instances are saved to local storage on each click. The image represents a single click of `#sidebar-nav a`:

[image]

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

**UPDATE**

I have narrowed down the problem. If I take out the following:

```
var uid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
    return v.toString(16);
});
```

and replace with a static variable like:

```
var uid = 'abc123';
```

it works fine and only adds a single entry into local storage as I expect. I then tried using the date and some math to generate a unique id like so:

```
var date = Date.now();
var uid = Math.round((Math.random() * date) / Math.random());
```

not as good I know but as soon as I clicked it again added the entry twice into local storage!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't click it twice? :) (or that the click handler is called twice)

Comment: Absolutely sure and no its the only piece of JS in my project so far

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint to the `localStorage.setItem` call and see if it is called twice.

Comment: I wonder if it's firing twice because it's registering the click event on the a tag as well as the parent #side-nav element.

Comment: @erahm The click event is registered only on the `a` tags inside a `#side-nav`. The selector is not a multiple selector ( `#side-nav, a` , notice the extra `,` between the selectors)

Comment: @christy As far as I can see no its not firing twice.